# PHP code to hide and unhide based on if the twitch stream is live has a resource error

Tags: php, live-streaming, twitch

I'm getting the following error:

> FATAL ERROR syntax error, unexpected 'http' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' on line number 8

when running the following code:

```
<?php
$streamChannel = "randomstream";  

$json_array = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams.json?channel=$streamChannel"), true);  

if(isset($json_array['streams'][0]['channel'])) {  
echo "<div id='streamonline'><iframe
src="http://player.twitch.tv/?channel=randomstream"
name="report"
height="100%"
width="100%"
frameborder="0"
scrolling="no"
allowfullscreen="true">
</iframe></div>";  
} else {  
echo "<div id='streamoffline'>Display 0</div>";  
}  

?>
```

The goal of this code is to only embed the live twitch stream when the stream is Live on the targeted website.

Comment: You need to escape " characters inside an " " string - use \"

Comment: @DaveS I'm sorry I don't understand it's ben a long time since I worked with this php code. are you saying div needs a /? Again sorry for the noobishness

Comment: Invalid: `echo "I like to say "Hello"";`  Valid: `echo "I like to say \"Hello\"";` . In most languages, you must escape the string start / end character when you use that character inside of a string.

Comment: i've tried to multiple variations... according to the twitch documentation this should be the correct code

Comment: Honestly im at a loss here nothing is working

Comment: This code shows the stream but does not hide an offline stream

Comment: Are you still getting the PHP compilation error?  Please edit your question to fix the code (all the nested "") to what actually compiles, and also list the problem(s) once the code runs.  It's a good idea to read [tour] then [ask] then [mcve]

Comment: Im not sure whats the problem at this point im ready to give up becuase the code loads both the offline and online option no matter if its online or not... I have an api key and everything added as well... twitch does not have a support team to reach out to so I guess I will not be implementing this. Stack only asks me to rephrase every question and consistently downvotes me and gives no help.

Comment: People usually only do that if you ignore [tour] and [ask] and [mcve].  If you want help here you need to be willing to follow the guidelines, and make the effort to fix your questions when they are not written correctly.  No one is being paid to help you so you should be willing to make an effort to do things right.  For example your question above is still the code that won't compile because of syntax errors.